# FInd rows with 0 count from group by sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query to select an ID and corresponding count  and group them based on ID and this is the sql for that

```
SELECT  InID, 
        COUNT(*) as ICount       
FROM RawData
WHERE CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  
AND  InID in (3851,4151,11)
GROUP BY InID
```

This returns only one record for me

```
4151   225
```

To find the missing entries ie 3851 and 11 , i tried the query

```
SELECT InID, 
       COUNT(*) as ICount 
FROM RawData
WHERE CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  
AND InID in (3851,4151,11)
GROUP BY InID
HAVING COUNT(*)=0
```

But it returned 0 records. So to check the IDs with missing records in a group by what is the proper way

Comment: Create a calendar table. Do an outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't return you a row if there are no records for the specified Id's That satisfy the condition in the Where Clause. You Can try this Logic

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT MyId = 3851
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4151
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11
)
SELECT
    CTE.MyId,
    COUNT(1)
    FROM CTE
        LEFT JOIN RawData RD
            ON CTE.MyId = RD.InID
        WHERE CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  
            AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate 
        GROUP BY CTE.MyId
```

Or Simply this will also work for you

```
select 
    InID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  
AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ICount 
    FROM RawData
        whereInID in (3851,4151,11)
        group by InID
```

To Filter records with Zero count

```
select 
        InID, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  
    AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ICount 
        FROM RawData
            whereInID in (3851,4151,11)
            group by InID
having SUM(CASE WHEN CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  
    AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Like the second approach , Can we make it to list  rows with 0 count only?

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:** I think you can achieve your desired output through `OUTER APPLY` as below:

```
SELECT InID, rd1.ICount      
FROM RawData rd
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) ICount 
            FROM RowDate rd1 
            WHERE rd1.InID = rd.InID 
            AND rd1.CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  
            AND rd1.CompletedDate<= @EndDate) rd1  
WHERE InID IN (3851,4151,11)
GROUP BY InID
```

IDs those doesn't have records will display `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT r.InID, ISNULL(c.ICount, 0) as ICount
FROM RawData r
    LEFT JOIN (
        select InID, COUNT(*) as ICount 
        FROM RawData
        where CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  
            and InID in (3851,4151,11)
        group by InID
    ) c ON c.InID = r.InID
WHERE r.InID in (3851,4151,11)
```

Using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT r.InID, ISNULL(c.ICount, 0) as ICount
FROM RawData r
    OUTER APPLY (
        select COUNT(*) as ICount 
        FROM RawData
        where CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  
            and InID = r.InID
    ) c 
WHERE r.InID in (3851,4151,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a left join from a resultset that contains all the values you want to include

```
select ids.Id, count(InId)
from 
(select 3851 as Id union select 4151 union select 11) ids
left join
    RawData
on ids.id = rawdata.inid
where CompletedDate>= @BeginDate  AND CompletedDate<= @EndDate  
group by Ids.id
```